# NextJS and Keycloak integration (Opt-out of Automatic Static Optimization issue)

Tags: next.js, keycloak

I am trying to integrate keycloak with NextJS.
The library that I am using is: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@react-keycloak/ssr

In documentation they said to wrap *SSRKeycloakProvider* component over the *App* component in **_app.tsx** file.

Like this:

```
function MyApp({ Component, pageProps, cookies }: AppProps & InitialProps) {
  return (
    <SSRKeycloakProvider
      keycloakConfig={keycloakCfg}
      persistor={SSRCookies(cookies)}
    >
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </SSRKeycloakProvider>
  )
}

...

MyApp.getInitialProps = async (context: AppContext) => {
  // Extract cookies from AppContext
  return {
    cookies: parseCookies(context?.ctx?.req),
  };
};
```

I have tested it and everything works fine, until I pushed my changes to gitlab and pipeline failed with error message:

> Warning: You have opted-out of Automatic Static Optimization due to
> `getInitialProps` in `pages/_app`. This does not opt-out pages with
> `getStaticProps` Read more:
> https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/opt-out-auto-static-optimization

Seems that this will cause that all pages without getStaticProps() method will be server side rendered. How to avoid that?

Should I create one more component which will look similiar like this *MyApp()*, and wrap it only over the pages that require keycloak authentification? (and then remove that SSRKeycloakProvider from MyApp and at this to that new one)

Comment: That message is simply a warning, why would it make your pipeline fail?